# Moved my bundle directory, so now it get's included in my GIT. Is there a wat to remove?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git

I moved my bundle directory for my ruby gems, but forgot to add the new directory to the .gitignore. So now my GIT is trying to push all the gems as well. I googled around, but I can't find a way to reset my GIT or remove the new bundle directory from the index.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can back them up(ie. move them out), get your gitignore adjusted, do a commit with this .gitignore and removals, then put them back after, then push.

So like this

- let git commit them (not push them) (suspect you already did this part, which is why your saying they are tied in now)
- move them out of your project file, and adjust your ignore file now

`mv new/gems some/ignored`

`vim .gitignore`

- git add. those changes which will set them for removal

`git add .`

- git commit which will delete them out of the repo (that which will be pushed)

`git commit -m "quick removal of supposed ignored gems"`

- now move your files gems back into their new ignored place

`mv some/ignored/gems new/`

`git status`

- you shouldn't see them listed anymore. now its safe to do your push

`git push`

Your mistake will become part of history, as well it should, to get you  into the proper habit of keeping commits, and not rebasing. Then you will see exactly what you did, and be able to back track easier.  Erasing mistakes can be costly, its best to just let the commit be if its a mistake, and add another commit to fix.   If pushing is involved this all can be done before pushing.

Dont push until its well and ready. spot qa test it after making adjustments one last time is a good habit just before pushing.  That gives you one last time to correct any mistakes you missed before release.

So never hesitate to commit, commit, commit!  Commit frequently, at logical breakpoints, and note your changelog briefs in bullets (hyphens) as comment `-m "new release of blah blah, - problem 1 fixed  - problem 2 fixed - etc.."`  on each commit

Comment: Thanks, pretty new to working with version control through GIT. The whole logic between pushes, commits and ignores begins to become a bit clearer now!